# Physics logo sending confusing signals?

Tags: discussion, design

Am I the only one who thinks the physics logo says "sombrero" louder than it says "physics"?

Comment: Note: I am but a laymen interested in physics, so perhaps I'm the exception...

Comment: It is the so called "Mexican hat" potential of the Goldstone spontaneous symmetry breaking mechanism. It is very recognizable to pros.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/949/2451

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the well known (among physicists and enthusiasts) as the [Mexican hat potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_hat_potential#A_pedagogical_example%3a_the_Mexican_hat_potential). It's involved in the mechanism of the Higgs Boson/God Particle.

Yes, it looks like a sombrero...

Anyways, I've never seen a sombrero made of green mesh.. IMO, *anything* that looks meshy is probably a graph.

I don't know about what most laymen would think, though.

Comment: It would be fun to test; I'm getting a P.SE tshirt sooner or later. Put tape on the sitename and roam around, asking people what they think it is. Of course, knowing me, they will know that it's not as simple as a sombrero :P

Comment: That would be awesome! You could ask people in a crowd somewhere where people wouldn't be so likely to catch on. lol

Comment: You should make a movie from walking around and asking people and put it on Youtube, LOl :-)

Comment: If you ask most non-programmers what the Stack Overflow logo is, they'd probably think of a slinky... the point is, having a logo that wouldn't be recognized by non-specialists is fine, and in fact one might argue that it bolsters the image of the site as being targeted at experts.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky Even as a (hobby) programmer, the logo only makes sense if you look at the sitename first. Otherwise it's a slinky. :) The math.SE one makes no sense either.

Comment: @Manishearth If you look carefully, the Math.SE logo is actually an impossible object similar to the Penrose triangle. Of course, if you look hard enough, Physics.SE's logo doesn't quite look like an Mexican hat either :P